# LASTools doesn't run in QGIS 3.2 on WIN because of encoding

Tags: qgis, las

I have a problem with LASTools in QGIS 3.2. I installed plugin, activated it in processing menu with correct path.
I tried to run lasview (I did the same process a day ago on ubuntu with WINE and everything was good), but I got only errormessage now. I check path for strange signs, but I can't seee nothing. In picutre you can see where error occure.

Picture of error log:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

I changed paths: in `options\treatments\treatment providers\LASTools` peak default to `C:\LASTools`; I point back to .`.\qgis\python\processing\plugins\processing\lidar` (lidar : folder created by myself where extracting the original file lastools.zip).

Then everything worked.

Qgis 3.8 zanzibar ; lastools 201909